# How to Define Typeclass Synonyms

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

In an attempt to make a sane(r) alternative to Haskell's numeric type system, the devs of [numeric-prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) slipped up and decided to name all of their type classes `C`. Aside from making the docs totally confusing, this means that I have to fully qualify all uses of the typeclasses:

```
import qualified Algebra.Additive (C)
import qualified Algebra.Ring (C)
...

newtype Foo a = Foo a

instance (Algebra.Additive.C a) => Algebra.Additive.C (Foo a) where ...

myadd :: (Algebra.Additive.C a) => a -> a -> a
myadd a b = ...
```

Also, since NumericPrelude has finer grained typeclasses, I usually have to import several different NumericPrelude modules. I can simplify this a little by defining top-level *constraint synonyms*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

module NPSynonyms (Additive) where

import qualified Algebra.Additive (C)

type Additive a = (Algebra.Additive.C a)
```

which allows me to make sane functions:

```
myadd :: (Additive a) => a -> a -> a
myadd a b = ...
```

However, when I need to define an instance, I still have to (also) import the original NumericPrelude class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

import NPSynonyms
import Algebra.Additive (C)

newtype Foo a = Foo a

instance (Additive a) => Algebra.Additive.C (Foo a) where ...
```

So instead of making `Additive` a *type* synonym with kind `Constraint`, what I'd *really* like is to define a *typeclass* synonym for the typeclass `Algebra.Additive.C`. Is there any way to do this in GHC 7.8, or is there any sane alternative?

Comment: Let's be specific. Only Henning Thielemann names all of his types `T` and all of his classes `C`. Everyone else knows it's terrible.

Comment: Does *he* know that it's terrible? I can try to convince him...

Comment: @Eric: don't bother.  He thinks it's the best thing ever.

Comment: Maybe somebody should just fork `numeric-prelude` to fix the names

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez That would probably be the best option. It's a shame that there's not really any moderation on Hackage. I've heard that he's clobbered some packages just to change all the class names to `C` and type names to `T`.

Comment: @DavidYoung Which packages has he modified?  Did he do this with the original author's consent?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I can't find anything too concrete, so I can't be sure, I heard about it on IRC. Here are a couple examples: http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=15744765&timestamp=1369191996#t1369191996 and http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=17202845&timestamp=1389145323#t1389145323. I can't say whether or not this was done without the author's consent without speculating, but it's suspicious to me. It also looks like he's done it to several packages, and since it's something that I would expect most people wouldn't like... http://hackage.haskell.org/user/HenningThielemann

Comment: It also doesn't display right on Hackage and I'd be surprised if many people would like instance lists that look like this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.0.3/docs/Algebra-Module.html

Comment: @DavidYoung Those instances are precisely what I mean about making the documentation unreadable. It is very frustrating to have to hover over hyperlinks and look at the address to read a constraint.

Comment: I don't think Henning ever changed anything without the original author's consent (or at least indifference).  Typically it's stuff that the original author is no longer interested in maintaining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> you have to fully qualify

No, not fully qualify.  Consider:

```
import qualified Algebra.Additive as Add

myadd :: Add.C a => a -> a -> a
```

That looks fairly readable to me.

EDIT:

Also consider making a superclass and treating that as an alias:

```
class (Add.C a, Ring.C a) => Num a where
instance Num Int
instance Num Word
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized I could shorten the qualification after I posted, thanks for pointing it out. Although I don't have a need to combine classes into a new one, is there any advantaged of using a new class to do so over my solution with `ConstraintKinds`?